# Changing text while pressing button android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, onclick, android-button

I've tried a tutorial on youtube but it doesn't work,when I click the button nothing happens.
When I press the button I want to Change the layout activity and also to be set on the new layout one random text from lets say other 10 and on this current layout I wanna have the button which will randomly change the first text to another one.
Here is what codes I've used and didn't worked out.

@I can't add the codes because It doesn't let me post it here..it says something like isn't valid but you see everything in the picture,so I did all that code and when I press on my button It doesn't doing anything,what can be the problem?and If you have any idea or if you know any tutorial to help me achieve what I said I want to do upper I would appreciate really much

@as you can see there is a string option which should give me one text of all of them when I click my button,but it doesn't

[sorry for image but it seems like those codes aren't good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6lvT.png)

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="332dp"
    android:layout_height="184dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <Button


        android:id="@+id/buttonsports"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="129dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ft"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="115dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="291dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sports"
        android:layout_width="216dp"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="95dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="246dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[this is how big my text box is,the "sports" is the id for TextView which is "abc"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcE0B.png)

Comment: please edit your question and include your code "Not the image of it" with more details to make it easier to help you

Comment: is it better?..

Comment: I just saw that the "TextView" is asking for a string,but that guy didn't made any in his video..could this be a solution?

Comment: give me the link of tutorial I'll see What's difference between it and your code

Comment: Give `LinearLayout's` height and width `wrap_content` and check if this issue is still there.

Comment: the linearlayout wrap_content didn't worked sorry for writing so late

Comment: here is the tutorial I can even use teamviewer if you want https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lj6qzHsgh_0

Comment: @AlexJ Can you try changing your `TextView` text Color to something like this? `android:textColor="#FF0000"`

Comment: omg dude I Love you..it works everything lol it was the text black damn it..got fooled once again by android studio =]

Answer (score 0):

In your xml you have a `LinearLayout` for which you have set the height to:

```
android:layout_height="184dp"
```

and inside there is a `Button` with height:

```
android:layout_height="129dp"
```

So for the `TextView` below there is left maximum `55dp` but you set:

```
android:layout_height="117dp"
```

This means that at least half the `TextView` is not visible.
In your code you set a random text to the `TextView` when you click the `Button`. 
You say that nothing happens. 
 
Is there a case that the text is being set but you can't see it because the `TextView` is mostly hidden? 
Change the heights of the views and you will find out.

Comment: It looks like the text have enough space but now I saw that the button doesn't work at all,like I have 1 more button with command onClickListener and It has 2 states focused and normal so this one which should generate me a random text doesn't change,I wonder if is because of missing onClickListener code

Comment: *It looks like the text have enough space* where? In the design preview? This has nothing to do with the real thing. You don't have 1 more Button if you do use the layout you posted. Set  the text of the TextView in xml like `android:text="abc"` and run the app. Do you see the text?

Comment: no, but even with abc it still tells me "hardcoded string "abc",should use @string" isn't this a solution?I wanna say my button is the mistake but It had no problems while using "onClickListener" to change layout,but for changing text doesn't work

Comment: * "hardcoded string "abc",...* is just a warning, not an error. You are not changing layouts with the code you posted. You are seting the text of the TextView and if you don't see even "abc" this is because the TextView is so far at the bottom.Change the heights.

Comment: I added one more picture to show how the text box looks like maybe you see if is wrong or not

Comment: omg dude I Love you..it works everything lol it was the text black damn it..got fooled once again by android studio =]